# "brush something up" vs. "brush up (on something)": What is the difference?

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions

For example, we have two sentences:

> I need to brush my French up a little bit. I need to brush up my
>   French.

and

> I need to brush up on my German. My German is weak. I had better brush
>   up.

Could you help me to understand what role is played by the preposition *on*?

Comment: While you're at it, [Brush Up Your Shakespeare](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJIpp2Jj8AQ). (There's no semantic difference between the two variations you're asking about.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preposition is optional. They both mean the same thing. You could say:

> I need to brush up my French.

Or

> I need to brush up on my French.

Here *brush up* and *brush up on* mean *to re-learn, improve, study, etc.*

Comment: For some, *on* is necessary in the phrase. I wonder if this is dialectal. I (AmE) never use *brush up* without the *on* and I thought it was an error recently when a learner said *brush up my English*.